# GROUP BY grouping multiple values as the same group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table similar to this:

```
ID      WEEK
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       2
6       3
7       3
8       3
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `week` FROM data GROUP BY `week`
```

Here's an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfdb6/2/0

What I need is to group rows every 2 weeks into the same COUNT.

So instead of this:

```
COUNT(*)    WEEK
3           1
2           2
3           3
3           4
```

I'd get:

```
COUNT(*)    WEEK
5           1
5           2
6           3
3           4
```

Where every week also has the next weeks COUNT added to it.

---

Question amended:

I should have been clear about what I really needed.

Rather than grouping weeks 1 and 3, what I need is grouping by **every 2 weeks**.

So group by weeks 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, 4 and 5, etc

Automatically if possible, but the sql could be generated outside the query for the week groupings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it for you...

First, get distinct weeks available from the data...
Then, join to the data but specifically on EITHER week or week +1

I applied this to your existing SQLFiddle and it appeared to work.

```
select
      JustWeeks.`week`,
      Count(*) as TwoWeekSum
   from
      ( select distinct
              `week`
           from
              data ) JustWeeks
      JOIN data 
         ON JustWeeks.`week` = data.`week`
         OR JustWeeks.`week` +1 = data.`week`
   group by
      JustWeeks.`week`
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm after! Thank you very much, @DRapp.

Answer (score 1):

create a case expression that represents the group buckets:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), case When week In (1,3) Then 'W13' Else 'W2' End
FROM data 
GROUP BY case When week In (1,3) Then 'W13' Else 'W2' End
```

Based on edited post, if week is integer, dividing by 2 will create what you want, since

```
 week    week/2
   0         0
   1         0
   2         1
   3         1
   4         2
   5         2
```

....... .etc.

so try this then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), week/2 
FROM data 
GROUP BY week/2
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems very similar to what I need. I've just updated the post because I left out some important details. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

you may look for this

```
   SELECT 
   case When week In  (1,3) Then ( select count(week) from data
                           where week in (1,3) ) 
   else ( select count(week) from data
                           where week =2 ) end count , week
   FROM data 
   group by count
  order by count desc
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfdb6/31)

output

```
  COUNT    week
    6       1
    2       2
```

Comment: Thanks echo_me, I've edited the question because I didn't explain it very well. I hope you can still help. Thanks.